# Что, если опускать аргументы (типы) для методов-дженериков?

Tags: java, generics

Я знаю, что если не указывать аргументы (вообще без угловых скобок) для классов-дженериков, то аргументами будет считаться тип `Objcect`, и что так "никто не делает".

**1. Но за что принимаются опущенные аргументы в случаи с методами-дженерииками?** Видимо по коду - не за `Object`):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list1.add(0);

        Collections.fill(list1, 111);
        System.out.println(list1); // [111] - сработало
    }
}
```

- Метод [fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html): `static <T> void    fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)`
- Для него аргумент мы не указали, но если бы за аргумент принялся
  `Object`, то метод бы не сработал в связи с: `(List<? super T> list, T 
  obj)`

**2. Стоит ли так делать (полностью опускать угловые скобки для методов-дженериков?** IDE мне никогда не предлагает их ставить...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **1. Но за что принимаются опущенные аргументы в случаи с методами-дженерииками?**

Реальные типы *выводятся* компилятором. Вывод типов — сложный и запутанный процесс с кучей нюансов. Ему посвящена целая глава спецификации Java ([Chapter 18. Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html)).

Если коротко, то компилятор пытается на основе переданных аргументов подобрать наиболее специфичный подходящий тип.

Для этого он берет метод:

```
<T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj)
```

, фактические аргументы и возвращаемое значение (здесь нет):

```
 Collections.fill(List<Integer>, int);
```

строит систему ограничений на `T`, принимает в расчет возможность оборачивания значений и определяет, что в данном случае `Integer` подходит как значение для  `T`.

Если вывести тип не получится, то компилятор выдаст ошибку. Например, код:

```
Collections.fill((list1, "111");
```

Приведет к ошибке:

```
error: method fill in class Collections cannot be applied to given types;
        Collections.fill(list1, "111");
                   ^
  required: List<? super T>,T
  found: List<Integer>,String
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: String
    upper bound(s): Integer,Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>fill(List<? super T>,T)
```

Т.е. компилятор не нашел такого `T`, которое приняло бы как `Integer` так и `String`.

> **2. Стоит ли так делать (полностью опускать фигурные скобки для методов-дженериков?**

Да, не нужно явно указывать тип без необходимости. Если Вы не используете несформированные типы, то в большинстве случаев компилятор сам справится с выводом.

Явное указание может понадобится в тех случаях, когда компилятор по каким-то причинам не может вывести нужный тип. Например, если у метода нет аргумента и по возвращаемому значению нельзя определить тип:

```
//метод принимает Object, но нужно передать ему список строк
someMethod(Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

Answer (score 2):

"*Для него аргумент мы не указали*"

указали неявно, подав аргумент типа `int`, запакованный затем в `Integer`.

"*Стоит ли так делать (полностью опускать фигурные скобки?)*"

Вы, видимо, хотели сказать "угловые"? Ну если это не затрудняет чтение текста, то почему бы и нет.